# C# MongoDB missing update aggregations pipline in strong type

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

Hi i want do update request like:

```
db.t1.update({ _id: ObjectId("5ec26497deb9782b501b3b7b") }, 
[

    { $addFields : { NextValue: { $sum: ['$seq',1] }} },
    { $addFields : { Obj: { name: "hi2", val: "$NextValue"  } } }
])
```

I use lastest mongodb and .net mongodb driver.

**Compatibility:**

[image]

**In changelog:**

> Update specification using an aggregation framework pipeline

But i miss set\addFields method, what am I doing wrong ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

these aggregation stages are not supported with .net driver yet. You can use:

```
coll.Aggregate().AppendStage<BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse("#your aggregation stage#"));
```